# Making a comment on facebook with curl without API

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I know there is a ready to use API for facebook, but since I last tried the API they change to much, now you need permissions an checks for everything you want to do ...
This project is only for personal usage, therefore I don't care about give my facebook password.

My goal is to make an comment to an picture on a facebook page, in this test aviciis

I created my first git repo https://github.com/fritz-net/facebook-AntiAPI because i have 4 files. For login etc. I hope this messy testing code is readable

The problem is that facebook shows an error that something happened (no acces, wrong page, out of date,... - German stuff),... even though the http headers are the same and the post data too. There is no point why facebook should not save this comment like any other. The login also worked well.

I'm using the mobile version because with the ajax/json version i had no real success either.

I hope I forget nothing about my problem in my tiredness. I tried to find other code from people who had done this, but everyone uses the api and I also tried to solve the problem myself for the last 6 hours (from about 02am till now 8) please excuse my bad English writing, dirty code and missing things

Maybe someone can give me a hint, good night

Comment: I don't understand why you would do something like you seem to work on... And I also can't understand how you'd come to the conclusion that the FB website won't change. In fact, I think it's much more likely to change than the Graph API itself.

Comment: Actually the project is done, facebook only has to accept the post.

You are totally right, facebook changes often, but sometimes people do things without real reasons. I thought it's a good training with regex and curl and as fast as using the api. Now I want to solve the problem because I was sitting there to long.

The whole thing is more about why the server won't accept my curl post not about facebook and it's api

Comment: Albeit that I think it's somehow useless, I don't think that anybody is able to help you with your problem if you don't show error messages etc. This is a programming site, and just linking to external code is not really enough...

Comment: I get no real error like you get when you have an syntax error. I think it also makes no sense if I copy 2 identical headers and the code is too long to put it here therefore I put it on git. I don't know where else I could ask and how I better should ask

Comment: You are supposed to use the API for that – and your “excuses” as to why you would not want to seem invalid to me. FB takes measures against people doing what you are trying to do – and even if you would get it to work, they could upgrade those measures one day later. So doing that would be _much more_ prone to stop working at any point, then doing it via API in the first place was.

Comment: thanks for you help and motivation, I solved the problem myself. In summary it was not that hard except fining this stupid mistake - next time i'll use a debugger.

I don't care if facebook change because this was only a challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that solution was very easy.

in the api.class.php there is a regex where I read out the form action, I added the following `$action = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $action);` and everything worked.

The problem where the html entities in the action url of the form

EDIT: I committed the changes to github for anyone interested